# Unity - Rigid Body Floats Away When Adding Ragdoll

Tags: unity, physics

I added a ragdoll component to my enemy model and now it just floats away whenever I run the game, this never happened before I added the ragdoll. if theres anything else I need to send just tell me because I'm not really sure

[[image: RigidBody]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: basically this happens every time I run the game now after adding ragdolls, they aren't affected by gravity https://imgur.com/a/NnuskIR